Grouping rows by day in unixtime
I have a table with DDL:
CREATE TABLE public.test_table (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    "date" int8 NOT NULL,
    user_id int4 NOT NULL,
    device_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_table_date_user_id_device_id_key UNIQUE (date, user_id, device_id),
    CONSTRAINT test_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE public.test_table ADD CONSTRAINT test_table FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES public.t_device(id);
ALTER TABLE public.test_table ADD CONSTRAINT test_table_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES public.t_user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;

Sample:
| id       | date           | user_id |
| -------- | -------------- | ------- |
| 1886     | 1716625890     | 5       |
| 1887     | 1716626430     | 5       |
| 1888     | 1716627030     | 5       |

And I need to find rows count grouped by days and also I need to print the first and the last dates in each day. As an input I have two dates: from and to and user_id.
I'm trying to use the following sql:
with calendar as (
select
    d
from
    generate_series(to_timestamp(:FROM)::date,
    to_timestamp(:TO)::date,
    interval '1 day') d)

select
    c.d::date as item_date,
    count(dt.id) as item_count,
    min(dt."date") as item_min,
    max(dt."date") as item_max
from
    test_table dt 
left join
     calendar c
     on
    to_timestamp(dt.date)::date >= c.d
    and
        to_timestamp(dt.date)::date < c.d + interval '1 day'
where dt.user_id = 5
group by
    c.d
order by
    c.d;


My current output:
|item_date |item_count|item_min     |item_max     |
|----------|----------|-------------|-------------|
|2024-05-25|144       |1,716,584,490|1,716,670,230|
|2024-05-26|144       |1,716,670,816|1,716,756,630|
|2024-05-27|144       |1,716,757,221|1,716,843,030|
|          |4,770     |1,716,286,230|1,719,514,890|

explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) result:
Sort  (cost=199067.86..199068.36 rows=200 width=36) (actual time=10.152..10.154 rows=3 loops=1)
  Output: ((d.d)::date), (count(dt.id)), (min(dt.date)), (max(dt.date)), d.d
  Sort Key: d.d
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
  Buffers: shared hit=363
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=199057.72..199060.22 rows=200 width=36) (actual time=10.144..10.146 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (d.d)::date, count(dt.id), min(dt.date), max(dt.date), d.d
        Group Key: d.d
        Buffers: shared hit=363
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..192966.61 rows=609111 width=20) (actual time=0.292..10.074 rows=432 loops=1)
              Output: d.d, dt.id, dt.date
              Join Filter: (((to_timestamp((dt.date)::double precision))::date >= d.d) AND ((to_timestamp((dt.date)::double precision))::date < (d.d + '1 day'::interval)))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 15174
              Buffers: shared hit=363
              ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.generate_series d  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Output: d.d
                    Function Call: generate_series((('2024-05-25 11:31:30+03'::timestamp with time zone)::date)::timestamp with time zone, (('2024-05-27 14:50:30+03'::timestamp with time zone)::date)::timestamp with time zone, '1 day'::interval)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.29..1100.30 rows=5482 width=12) (actual time=0.011..1.198 rows=5202 loops=3)
                    Output: dt.id, dt.date
                    Buffers: shared hit=363
                    ->  Index Scan using test_table_date_user_id_device_id_key on public.test_table dt  (cost=0.29..1072.89 rows=5482 width=12) (actual time=0.032..2.070 rows=5202 loops=1)
                          Output: dt.id, dt.date
                          Index Cond: (dt.user_id = 5)
                          Buffers: shared hit=363
Settings: effective_cache_size = '1377MB', effective_io_concurrency = '200', max_parallel_workers = '1', random_page_cost = '1.1', search_path = 'public, public, "$user"', work_mem = '524kB'
Planning Time: 0.147 ms
Execution Time: 10.264 ms


Is the query optimal?
Is it possible to remove the last total row in the result? (Updated: fixed, my mistake, thank you Frank Heikens)


Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? If you don't want records without a match, don' use a LEFT JOIN but an INNER JOIN.

@FrankHeikens thx, I have added DDL and the result from explain

Offtopic: Why is your work_mem to extremely small? Anything below 1MB is imho a bad idea, you're forcing the database to use disk for almost everything. And that's so much slower than RAM, even when using SSD.

@FrankHeikens it is an external server for me, so I don't know the answer. but it is a really good question, I will try to ask, thank you for noticing.


Is the query optimal?

It's not. The CTE is unnecessary - you're already turning your unix timestamp into a date by to_timestamp(dt.date)::date. I don't see a reason to generate mismatched dates with generate_series().

Is it possible to remove the last total row in the result?

It's there because 4,770 dates you generated in the CTE don't match anything in test_table. If you remove the CTE, you'll get rid of that last line, shorten, simplify and speed up your query:
demo at db<>fiddle
select
    to_timestamp(dt.date)::date as item_date,
    count(dt.id) as item_count,
    min(dt."date") as item_min,
    max(dt."date") as item_max
from
    test_table dt 
where dt.user_id = 5
--and to_timestamp(dt.date)::date >= to_timestamp(:FROM)::date
--and to_timestamp(dt.date)::date <  to_timestamp(:TO)::date
group by
    item_date
order by
    item_date;




item_date
item_count
item_min
item_max




2024-05-24
144
1716509706
1716591459


2024-05-25
144
1716595589
1716677784


2024-05-26
144
1716682103
1716764034



If generate_series() was there to narrow down to a target period (of what looks like 13 years), you can uncomment the two added conditions above.
Both bigint and timestamp(tz) are 8 bytes. If you have control over the schema, changing the column type won't cost any additional space and it'll make it easier to work with it, enabling all built-in functions and operators without the need to run it through to_timestamp() every time.
Nitpicking, because dt.id is likely a primary key implying not null but it's good to make sure you're intentionally not counting rows where dt.id is null:

count ( * ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows.


count ( "any" ) → bigint
Computes the number of input rows in which the input value is not null.

When you use a full or right join, even though the column in the left table isn't nullable, it'll hold a null for all rows without a matching right.

Thank you so much, I overcomplicated the problem, your answer is easier and faster
